# How to avoid skipping elements of an array while looping on it

Tags: arrays, typescript

l have an Angular project that rounds the `moment.js` time object to next nearest 15 minute interval to loop satellite image weather. I pushed `moment.js` time as array and when I run that array for looping, some elements are being skipped.

example : `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];`

when I run the code I got like that: `["1", "3", "5"];`

Any solution to run the array without skipping any elements?

[Live Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g8q8j4?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: If you mean `this.timeStops` then it has 15 elements as it supposed to be by running `for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++)`. What's wrong?

Comment: the wrong is i don't know why he is skip element . watch     `{{image$|async}}` how time is skip . check out the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g8q8j4?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I think the issue with `calculateIndex()`